# Operation puppeteer without Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How can I use a puppeteer without a chrome browser? Parasizing the page is over, but if I want to put it on an external server for the example of VPS, it is necessary for the page's JavaScript to be parsed so that all the page content is loaded. If I disable the browser by:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false
});
```

This page paring works only for pure HTML code, JavaScript does not run. What should I configure to make the puppeter work without running the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot operate puppeteer without Chrome. It only works with Chrome.
You could see the README https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer at FAQ
It says

> Puppeteer works only with Chromium or Chrome. However, many teams only run unit tests with a single browser (e.g. PhantomJS). In non-testing use cases, Puppeteer provides a powerful but simple API because it's only targeting one browser that enables you to rapidly develop automation scripts.
>   Puppeteer bundles the latest versions of Chromium.

Comment: OK thank you for your answer. But if you run the script on the VPS server, the script will work mormally without any errors?

Comment: When you install Puppeteer, it downloads a recent version of Chromium (~170Mb Mac, ~282Mb Linux, ~280Mb Win) that is guaranteed to work with the API. To skip the download, see Environment variables.